# Finding Eigenvalue after Diagonalizing Hamiltonian with Bogoliubov Transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I got a paper that calculates the dispersion relation of anti-ferromagnetic spinwave. At one point, they use Bogoliubov transformation to diagonalize the Hamiltonian.

I don't understand how they got the value for $u_k^2$ and $v_k^2$. Also, what is the $\Delta$, and how they figured out the eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Here is the part of the problem that I am talking about:

[image: bogoliubov]

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which paper?

Comment: I actually got this from my professor, he said some postdoc has written it for him.

I can give you the full paper if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we basically have two equations with two unknowns, A and F:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
F(u_k^2 + v_k^2)+2Au_kv_k &=& 0 \\
u_k^2 - v_k^2 &=& 1
\label{twoeqs}
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

We make the following substitutions:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
u_k =& \cosh{\theta_k} \\
v_k =& \sinh{\theta_k} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

Substituting this into Eq. \ref{twoeqs}. The second one $u_k^2 - v_k^2 = 1$ is already satisfied. For the first one:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
 &F[\sinh{\theta_k}^2 + \cosh{\theta_k}^2] + A(2\sinh{\theta_k}\cosh{\theta_k}) = 0 \\
\Rightarrow &F\cosh{2\theta_k} + A\sinh{2\theta_k} = 0 \\
\Rightarrow &(F\sqrt{1-\sinh{2\theta_k}^2})^2 = A^2\sinh{2\theta_k}^2 \\
\Rightarrow &\sinh{2\theta_k} = -\frac{F}{\sqrt{A^2-F^2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

Plugging this value to $\cosh{\theta_k}^2 = \sinh{\theta_k}^2 +1$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
\cosh{2\theta_k} = \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2-F^2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

We define:

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{aligned}
\omega_k &= A(u_k^2 + v_k^2)+2Fu_kv_k \\
&= A\cosh{2\theta_k}+ F\sinh{2\theta_k} \\
&= \sqrt{A^2 - F^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{eqnarray}

So the final Hamiltonian is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
H \approx\: E_0 + AN &+ \sum_{k}\omega_k(\alpha_k^+\alpha_k + \beta_k^+\beta_k)
\end{aligned}
\label{newH10}
\end{equation}

Comment: The Bogoliugov variables are $u$ and $v$, not $\mu$ and $v$. You stray from that (firmly established) convention at your peril - the only thing your change in notation will accomplish is to confuse your readers for no good reason.